# Alternative to the: mov ax,data mov ds,ax instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

Basically I have an assignment, & there is some simple code, but one of the questions is to type a equivalent instruction to:

```
mov ax,data
```

By using an label (array) inside the data segment, & I can't figure it out or find anything on it:

```
 CODE   SEGMENT
 START: MOV AX, DATA
 MOV DS, AX
 MOV CX, 3
 MOV SI, OFFSET array
ITER: MOV AX, [SI]
XCHG AH, AL
ROL AX, 1
INC SI
AND [SI], AX
LOOP ITER
ENDS

DATA    SEGMENT
DB 1 DUP (0)
array DB 0B9H,8BH,01H,70H,02H,06H,34H,0CH ; this one here
ENDS

END START
```

Comment: I know, sorry, but I have to use array somehow.

Comment: Maybe they are thinking of replacing `MOV SI, OFFSET array` with `LEA SI, array`?

Comment: idk, would be easy if that is the case, but here is the exact question: Write an equivalent instruction to MOV AX,DATA  using array. (3 marks)

Comment: Really don't know, but thx for trying, i appreciate it. Will mail the lecturer, but he usually doesn't like to give hints.

Comment: It occurred to me that they might be asking to replace `MOV AX, DATA` with  `MOV AX, seg array`

Comment: Yep that seems to be it, he also confirmed.

Comment: BTW common way in 256B intros to load particular value into segment register was using stack `push 0a000h` `pop es`. This is slower than the `mov ax,...` variant, but it keeps value in `ax` unchanged and the machine code is 1 byte shorter IIRC.

Comment: If you are trying to transfer data of some variable to ax without using `mov ax, data` then you could achieve this by first XORing the AX to itself and then ORing it with the variable whose value you want to transfer to AX for eg: `1. XOR AX, AX  2. OR AX, varName`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out what you're actually wanting.
But if you want the alternative of
 `MOV AX, DATA`
This can be used   -

```
LEA AX, DATA
```

LEA is **Load Effective Address** which will load AX with the first address of DATA.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** : `mov AX, SEG array`

---

It appears that my comment under the answer was correct according to the OP. At first it wasn't entirely clear what was being ask, but this seems to be the question:

> Using a label `array` defined inside the `DATA` segment, provide another instruction that would be equivalent to `mov AX,DATA`

When worded this way the answer is more clear. When a label is placed into a segment the label has both an offset relative to the beginning of the segment and a segment value. This can come in handy when producing an executable using a memory model that may allow multiple data segments. With `mov ax, DATA`, `DATA` is the name of the segment, thus this instruction moves the segment value into *AX*<sup>1</sup>.

Given a label in a segment, how can you get the segment value? The answer is simple. Most people who work with *MASM/TASM* use the **OFFSET** keyword to get the offset of a label in memory (relative to the segment). The keyword **SEG** is a similar but represents the segment value of the segment containing the label.

The segment and offset create a [segment:offset](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) pair that is the basis for accessing 1MiB in real mode with 16-bit registers.

The instruction that would have been equivalent would have been:

```
mov AX, SEG array
```

This moves the segment value of `array` into *AX*. Since `array` is in the `DATA` segment it makes the two instructions equivalent.

---

<sup>1</sup> Segment values are fixed up by the DOS EXE program loader since they are only fully known when the program is loaded into RAM.